# Add submit button to SearchView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, searchview

I tried to implement a `SearchView` in `ToolBar`. When I try to use this option to submit my query, the submit button is located inside the `ToolBar`. However, I need the button inside the `SearchView`.

How can I customise the `SearchView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true)`.

This will show default search submit button inside searchview.

Answer (score 1):

#### Android SearchView customisation

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAsh"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAsh"
    android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:commitIcon="@drawable/ic_commit"
    android:searchHintIcon="@drawable/ic_search" 
    android:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close" 
    android:goIcon="@drawable/ic_go">

</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
```

Dont forget to change these icons.

And follow this [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html) to know each option of SearchView .